# How to obtain title attribute using python and beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, html, selenium, beautifulsoup

Assume the following:

```
<td title="I want this title" role="gridcell"><a onclick="open" href="#">TEXT</a></td>
```

Now, I've successfully found respectively the table and individual rows using:

```
for rows in soup.find_all(['tr']):
    for cells in rows.find_all(['td']):
```

By printing `cells` I can see I've found the correct rows, but I'm really not sure how to take the title attribute and save it as a string? I've attempted to use `temp = soup.find('td')['title']`, but I'm getting errors doing this, so evidently I'm doing something wrong.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get an attribute of an element, you can treat *an element as a dictionary* ([reference](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attributes)):

```
soup.find('tag_name')['attribute_name']
```

And, in your case:

```
for tr in soup.find_all('tr'):
    for td in tr.find_all('td'):
        print(td.get('title', 'No title attribute'))
```

Note that I've used `.get()` method to avoid failing on `td` elements with no `title` attribute.

Answer (score 2):

The **lxml** library is often useful too, because it makes it possible to identify HTML structures using **xpath** expressions which can make for more compact codes.

In this case, the xpath expression `//td[@title]` asks for all `td` elements but insists that the `title` attribute be present. In the for-loop you see that there is no need to check for the presence of the attribute as this has already been done.

```
>>> from io import StringIO
>>> HTML = StringIO('''\
... <td title="title 1" role="gridcell"><a onclick="open" href="#">TEXT</a></td>
... <td role="gridcell"><a onclick="open" href="#">TEXT</a></td>
... <td title="title 2" role="gridcell"><a onclick="open" href="#">TEXT</a></td>
... <td title="title 3" role="gridcell"><a onclick="open" href="#">TEXT</a></td>''')
>>> parser = etree.HTMLParser()
>>> tree = etree.parse(HTML, parser)
>>> tds = tree.findall('//td[@title]')
>>> tds
[<Element td at 0x7a0888>, <Element td at 0x7a0d08>, <Element td at 0x7ae588>]
>>> for item in tree.findall('//td[@title]'):
...     item.attrib['title']
...     
'title 1'
'title 2'
'title 3'
```

Comment: Hi Bill, I very much appreciate you adding an alternative method for this. I will definitely try this out too; if anything then for the sake of learning. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_data, 'html5lib')
tag_object=soup.title
tag_object
```