# How to extract info in the title from div in beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract just the rating from the html posted in the screenshot. It is embedded in title under div. This code below returns "None"

HTML:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
type(html_soup)

rest_container = html_soup.find_all('div', 
     class_ = 'i-stars i-stars--regular-5 rating-large')

first_rest=rest_container[0]

print (first_rest.text)
```

[image: Screenshot of HTML]

Comment: Please paste the HTML into the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to obtain title attribute using python and beautifulsoup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43005780/how-to-obtain-title-attribute-using-python-and-beautifulsoup)

Comment: <div class="i-stars i-stars--regular-5 rating-large" title="5.0 star rating">
        <img class="offscreen" height="303" src="https://s3-media2.fl.yelpcdn.com/assets/srv0/yelp_design_web/9b34e39ccbeb/assets/img/stars/stars.png" width="84" alt="5.0 star rating">
    </div>

Comment: @AshwinAthrey Take a look at the edit I made. It fixes the indentation so that your HTML shows up and your Python is formatted as code.

Comment: @shahin, Sorry about that. Edited accordingly

Comment: It's okay. Comment taken out.

Answer (score 3):

You haven't provided sufficient element for us to give you any solution. However, give this a go. Just input an `url` within the script. Hope it will at least fetch you the rating.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "" #input webpage link here
res = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html5lib')
for rating in soup.select(".rating-large"):
    print(rating.get("title"))
```