# print div content python

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, scrape

[image]

How can I print "Saturday 8th of February 2020 07:46:40 PM CDT"?
I have googled a lot and tried many times. Can someone help me?

Comment: A simple googling: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43005780/how-to-obtain-title-attribute-using-python-and-beautifulsoup
Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: A simple googling:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43005780/how-to-obtain-title-attribute-using-python-and-beautifulsoup
Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Please [edit] your code showing us what you have already tried. Providing a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

Kindly, DO NOT paste an `HTML` code as `IMAGE` within your future question, To make it easier, Please post the `HTML` as a code.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<div class="date">
<span title="Hi">Bye</span>
</div>"""


soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
print(soup.select_one('.date>span')['title'])
```

Output:

```
Hi
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use `get_attribute` method which is available in Selenium.

```
title_value = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class = 'date']/span[@title]").get_attribute('title')
print(title_value)
```

Comment: Based on what you providing an answer for `Selenium` as the `OP` didn't mentioned that he's using `selenium` at all?

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη : it is tagged my friend :)

Comment: we aren't supposed to guess from tag :D as `bs4` is tagged as well. :D and `Python` wide selection.

Comment: Well you might have guessed as well since your answer us in bs4.